# Hotcakes Commerce DrillDown view logic

Tags: e-commerce

I'm trying to add a small bit of logic to the Hotcakes DrillDown view. During the foreach loop on the Products array, I'd like to check to see if the product name contains a specific substring, and if it does, add some html markup for that product. I've looked at the If Binding in Knockout but the examples seem to show to if a property is equal to some value. I want to check to see if the property contains a certain value.

```
<!-- ko if: Products().ProductName.contains('string') -->
     <div >This product contains substring</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an error message that says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return Products }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return Products().ProductName.contains('string') }"
>   Message: Products is not defined

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using version 1.xx of Hotcakes, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 01.10.03

Comment: Sorry for the follow-up question, but I forgot to ask you.  Which view file are you trying this with, and where in that file?  It will help out a lot as I try to determine a proper answer for you.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the DrillDown.cshtml file. Specifically inside the `            <div class="hc-record-grid hc-product-grid clearfix" data-bind="foreach: Products"></div>. When it uses KO to loop through the products, I'd like to check to see if the product name contains a specific substring.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do needs to be updated in the Category JS file, and not just in the markup itself.  This is because the views are using KnockoutJS for binding the product data.  You'll see a complete answer of this in your other question.

[Hotcakes Commerce Extending the DrillDown ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901080/hotcakes-commerce-extending-the-drilldown-viewmodel)